# Evaluate $\int \frac{dx}{(x-1)^{\frac 34} (x+2)^{\frac 54}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Given that $\int \frac{1}{(x-1)^{\frac 34} (x+2)^{\frac 54}}dx$

Let $(x-1)^{\frac 14} = t$

So the integral becomes $$\int \frac{4}{(t^4+3)^{\frac 54}} dx$$

How do I solve it further?

Comment: Possibly helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628155/the-integral-int-frac-rm-dxx3-frac87x-2-frac-67

Comment: $x-1=t^4$, so $dx=4t^3\,dt$; then let $u=t^4+3$.

Comment: @0-thUserSumanta yes it’s very helpful

Comment: The original question was stated in terms of $x$, not $t$, so the final answer must also involve $x$, and not $t$. You have accepted an answer that has only $t$ in it, and not $x$. Do you know how to convert that answer to a formula in $x$? And have you checked that it gives the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

Note that\begin{align}\frac1{(x-1)^{3/4}(x+2)^{5/4}}&=\frac{(x-1)^{-3/4}(x+2)^{-3/4}}{(x+2)^{2/4}}\\&=\frac{(x-1)^{-3/4}(x+2)^{-3/4}}{\bigl((x+2)^{1/4}\bigr)^2}.\end{align}On the other hand,$$(x-1)^{-3/4}=4\bigl((x-1)^{1/4}\bigr)'\quad\text{and}\quad(x+2)^{-3/4}=4\bigl((x+1)^{1/4}\bigr)',$$from which it follows that\begin{align}(x-1)^{-3/4}(x+2)^{-3/4}&=\frac13(x-1)^{-3/4}(x+2)^{-3/4}\bigl((x+2)-(x-1)\bigr)\\&=\frac13\bigl((x-1)^{-3/4}(x+2)^{1/4}-(x-1)^{1/4}(x+2)^{-3/4}\bigr)\\&=\frac43\left((x+2)^{1/4}\bigl((x-1)^{1/4}\bigr)'-(x-1)^{1/4}\bigl((x+1)^{1/4}\bigr)'\right).\end{align}Therefore,\begin{align}\frac1{(x-1)^{3/4}(x+2)^{5/4}}&=\frac{\frac43\left((x+2)^{1/4}\bigl((x-1)^{1/4}\bigr)'-(x-1)^{1/4}\bigl((x+1)^{1/4}\bigr)'\right)}{\bigl((x+2)^{1/4}\bigr)^2}\\&=\frac43\left(\frac{(x-1)^{1/4}}{(x+2)^{1/4}}\right)'.\end{align}So,$$\int\frac1{(x-1)^{3/4}(x+2)^{5/4}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac43\frac{(x-1)^{1/4}}{(x+2)^{1/4}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Continue with

$$I=\int \frac{4}{(t^4+3)^{\frac 54}} dt$$

and substitute
$$\frac3{u^4}=1+\frac3{t^4}\>\>\> \implies \>\>\>t^4+3= \frac9{3-u^4},\>\>\>dt = \frac{3^{\frac54}}{(3-u^4)^{\frac54}}du
$$

Then

$$I= \frac4{3^{\frac54}}\int du=\frac {4t}{3(t^4+3)^{\frac14}}+C
$$

Comment: Hold on, Aditya has written $\int4(t^4+3)^{-5/4}\,dx$, but you are doing $\int4(t^4+3)^{-5/4}\,dt$. That's not the same thing. And how do you get the formula for $dt$?